# SEO Site Title appearing in google search despite not being added

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, google-search

I am using Yoast SEO plugin for my WordPress website. I have not added Site Title to SEO Title in Yoast Content-Type Post settings or the post itself but it is still showing Site Title when the post is searched on google such as https://homekitchenary.com/best-water-softeners/ is displayed as "Best Water Softener of 2019 - Buyer's Guide - Home Kitchenary". This is happening with most of the posts despite not having Site Title in them. The preview snippet does not show Site title but it appears on google search. There are few posts that are not showing the Site title such as https://homekitchenary.com/best-hard-anodized-cookware-set/ displayed as "10 Best Hard Anodized Cookware Set 2019 - Buyers Guide"  and checked if there are any differences in them but there were not any.

Comment: Can you check the meta tags generated in your page headers? (I’m not sure what ‘SEO title’ is, but I’d guess it’s a meta tag?) Sometimes the theme will add headers too so it may not actually be Yoast, but the Yoast headers are surrounded by a comment block and so are easy to identify.

Comment: I have checked meta tags they are only showing post title and not Site title in the title meta tag